# How to insert variable value to already existing string python?

Tags: python, string

How to Insert variable value to string python?
I need to insert 'g' value to {g} in html text.
[image: code]

tried f string and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert value into `{g}` in your example

```
g = 234

text = '''
<p>Hi {g}!</p>
'''

print(text.format(g=g))
```